# Chrome Canvas Linear Gradient != Firefox Canvas Linear Gradient

Tags: firefox, html, google-chrome, canvas, gradient

Well , the problem is the next :

```
   canvas = GreenCanvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
   grad = canvas.createLinearGradient(0,0,255,0);
   grad.addColorStop(0, 'rgb('+r+','+0+','+b+')');
   grad.addColorStop(1, 'rgb('+r+','+255+','+b+')');
   canvas.fillStyle = grad;
   canvas.fillRect(0,0,256,34);
```

256 pixels . from for example rgb(0,0,0) to rgb(0,255,0)

Chrome 6.0.472: gradient (0,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,2,0) (0,3,0) (0,4,0) ... (0,255,0)

Firefox 3.6.6: gradient (0,0,0) (0,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,2,0) ... (0,255,0)

i would like to see who programs that gradient function in firefox  . But anyway , i would like to know if its a real problem , or is that in firefox the gradient is done that manner. Or if it exist another manner to do a well done gradient without using too much memory.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying the problem is?  Where do the variables r and b come from?  Do you have screenshots of how it looks in the two browsers?

Comment: the problem is that in firefox , when you try from 0..255 colour number , it repeats the first

Answer (score 1):

It's known that Chrome has problems with the Canvas gradients at the moment.

I submitted a bug to Chromium because of how many of hixie's (the specification writer) tests were failing on Chrome.

In short, you can't make your 'grad' variable. You have to set it directly.

This works:

```
   var context = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
   context.fillStyle = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 500, 300);
   context.fillStyle.addColorStop(0, '#0000ff');
   context.fillStyle.addColorStop(1, '#ff00ff');
   context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
```

This does NOT work, even though they are SUPPOSED to do the same thing:

```
   var context = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
   var g = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 500, 300);
   g.addColorStop(0, '#0000ff');
   g.addColorStop(1, '#ff00ff');
   context.fillStyle = g;
   context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
```

**For now, just do it the first way.**

Here's the filed bug report from early September.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54070&can=4&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS

Comment: mmm , but the problem is with firefox not with chrome . Anyway ill try to do that manner to see the differences and tomorrow ill promise to answer (here is late now )